# Como fazer o resultado de uma coluna?

Tags: php, html5, mysqli

```html
if(($resultado_usuario) AND ($resultado_usuario->num_rows != 0)){
 ?>
  <style>
 
 tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #CCC}
     
 </style>
 

 
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
   <tr>
   
   <th><h4><span style="color: black"><strong>ID</th>
   <th><h4><span style="color: black"><strong>Tipo de Venda</th>
   <th><h4><span style="color: black"><strong>Tipo de Pagamento</th>
   <th><h4><span style="color: black"><strong>Total</th>

   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <?php
   while($row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario)){
    ?>
    <tr>
        
     <td><?php echo $row_usuario['id']; ?></th>
     <td><?php echo $row_usuario['tipo_venda']; ?></th>
     <td><?php echo $row_usuario['tipo']; ?></th>
     <td><?php echo $row_usuario['total']; ?></th>

     
     
    

    </tr>
    <?php
   }?>
  </tbody>
 </table>
<?php
```

Tenha essa tabela que e formada apos um consulta no banco de dados aonde o resultado e o seguinte: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha duvida no campo Total como faço para somar todos os resultado ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode ir somando dentro do `while`

```
   <?php
    $valorTotal = 0;    
    while($row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario)){
            $valorTotal += $row_usuario['total'];
    ?>
```

Depois você usa a variável `$valorTotal` no lugar apropriado

Tipo isso:

```
 <tbody>
         <?php
         $valorTotal = 0;   
         while($row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario)){
            $valorTotal += $row_usuario['total'];
         ?>
            <tr>

                <td><?php echo $row_usuario['id']; ?></th>
                <td><?php echo $row_usuario['tipo_venda']; ?></th>
                <td><?php echo $row_usuario['tipo']; ?></th>
                <td><?php echo $row_usuario['total']; ?></th>


            </tr>
            <?php
        }?>
        <tr>
           <td>Total:</th>
           <td><?php echo $valorTotal; ?></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```